# Reserve space on screen for window

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am creating desktop environment and I need to reserve space on top of the screen for taskbar. Currently it is impossible to close (for example) Chromium - close/maximize/minimize buttons are behind the taskbar. How to reserve space on screen?

Here is the code:

```
#include "status_bar.h"
#include "ui_status_bar.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <QTime>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include "menu.h"
#include "ui_menu.h"

status_bar::status_bar(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::status_bar)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
move(0,0);
menudialog = new QDialog(0,0);
setMinimumSize(QApplication::desktop()->width(),36);
setMaximumSize(QApplication::desktop()->width(),36);
ui->menu_switch->move(size().width()/2-ui->menu_switch->size().width(),0);
ui->time->move(QApplication::desktop()->width()-ui->time->size().width(),10);
ui->username->setText(getenv("USER"));
timeupdate = new QTimer(this);
is_menu_open=false;
connect(timeupdate, SIGNAL(timeout()),
          this, SLOT(UpdateClock()));
timeupdate->start(100);
}

void status_bar::UpdateClock()
{
    ui->time->setText(QTime::currentTime().toString("HH:mm"));
}

status_bar::~status_bar()
{
    delete ui;
}

void status_bar::on_menu_switch_clicked()
{
    if(is_menu_open) {
        menudialog->close();
        is_menu_open=false;
    } else {
       is_menu_open=true;
        Ui_menu menuui;
        menuui.setupUi(menudialog);
        menudialog->setMinimumSize(QApplication::desktop()->width(),QApplication::desktop()->height()-36);
       menudialog->setMaximumSize(QApplication::desktop()->width(),QApplication::desktop()->height()-36);
        menudialog->move(0,36);
        menudialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
        menudialog->show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's is the question/problem?

Comment: How can I dock the window to top of the screen?

Comment: Unsure how to prevent your taskbar to overlap other program windows, though. These flags work for me. Most of them you've specified already but Qt::CustomizeWindowHint. Try combination that suits you.

    setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

Comment: Red border is not result I want. In Google I cannot find anything about docking window to top of the screen. Applications are hiding behind the taskbar.

Comment: What is your window manager?